# addObjectsFromArray Not available in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, merge

I have been looking for a method which can merge my arrays in one array in Swift. I have 2 NSMutableArrays and I want to add contents of arrays in new array.

Example: In Objective C

```
NSMutableArray a = [1,2,3];
NSMutableArray b = [a,b,c];
NSMutableArray c = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[c addObjectsFromArray:a];
[c addObjectsFromArray:b]; 
// Output : c = [1,2,3,a,b,c]
```

But In Swift I am facing a problem. I have tried "+", "append" () and addObjects(from:) but nothing is giving required answer. append(contentsOf:) does not seem to work. Xcode suggest to delete "contentsOf:". Can anyone give me a small solution for that? Please don't suggest for loop.

Comment: Xcode is giving error to delete it

Comment: @MSwapnil In swift you have used `NSMutableArray` or swift native array?

Comment: I have used Bridge header,, So arrays are NSMutableArray but I want to merge in swift

Comment: Update your question with your tried in swift and also the declaration of array.

Comment: @MSwapnil, what do you mean by  `[a,b,c]`. Are `a, b, c` strings or some other objects?

Comment: Basically don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Objective-C code directly translates to the following in `swift 3`

```
var a:NSMutableArray = [1,2,3];
var b:NSMutableArray = ["a","b","c"];
var c:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
c.addObjects(from: a as [AnyObject])
c.addObjects(from: b as [AnyObject])
c.add([a, b]) // a, b are arrays
```

result: `c = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c", [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]]`

If you want to use a `swift` array:

```
var a:[Any] = [1,2,3];
var b:[Any] = ["a","b","c"];
var c:[Any] = [Any]();
c.append(contentsOf: a)
c.append(contentsOf: b)
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

result: `c = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c", [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]`

From the discussion, I believe that the below picture contains the problem you're facing:

[image]

If you are trying to add contents of `NSMutableArray` to a swift array, casting the `NSMutableArray` to `[AnyObject]` will help. You can do it in the following way.

`Example:`

```
var b:NSMutableArray = ["a","b","c"];
var d:[AnyObject] = []
d.append(contentsOf: b as [AnyObject])
```

result: `d = ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Simpler:  `c.addObjects(from: a as [AnyObject])`

Comment: addObjects(from:) is adding array as element... It means if both arrays have 4-4 element then the result array will only contains 2 element both are arrays with 4-4 elements

Comment: @MSwapnil, `addObjects(from:)` in swift is not adding array as element. It means adding all elements inside the input array to the current array. `add()` is adding array as an element

Comment: @MSwapnil, can you please tell me whether my edited answer contains what you're looking for

Comment: No its not working.. I already told in question I have 2 objective C Mutablearrays

Comment: When I try to create array from mutable array then properties got change and contentsOf not available for resulting array

Comment: @MSwapnil, check the edited answer. I believe that this should solve the problem

Comment: It is common problem of typecasting between swift and objective C

Answer (score 1):

Use `append(contentsOf: C)` method-

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
var arr2 = [4]
arr2.append(contentsOf: arr1)
//[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
var arr1 = [7, 8]
arr.insert(contentsOf: arr1, at: 0)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Not working!! I have MutableArray and += cannot be applied to operands of type 2 MutableArrays

Comment: Could you look one more time.

Comment: it will run in normal method but when I tried to initialize from NSMutableArray then it is giving error to delete contentsOf: